# Eclipse Kepler can't install PHP PDT

Tags: eclipse

I installed eclipse kepler SR2 in my windows 8 PC, but I can't install PHP.

PDT (http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.6) raises

> No repository found at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.6. No repository found
>   at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.6.

[image: error]

Does anyone know the fix?

Is Kepler the right package for PHP?

Comment: Well Kepler is two releases out of date. Eclipse Mars is the current release. The `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.6` repository responds for me (testing with Eclipse Mars).

Comment: @greg-449 . is this right one https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-450-m1/marsm1

Comment: Go to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and choose 'Eclipse for PHP Developers'